# UICollectionView scroll changes color of navigation and tab how

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I am building an iOS application and have done all the layouts using storyboards and auto layout.

I have a `ViewController` as follows

[image]

For the `CollectionView` I have specified it to have 4 cells.

The issue I'm having that when I scroll vertically, the background colour of the Navigation bar and Tab bar changes.

How can I make sure that the background colour is not changed when I scroll.

This is what happening when I scroll - You can see the background colour of the navigation and tab bar change.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested you can set the toolbar and navigation bar's translucent property to false, but you can also do this in the storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

your navigation bar and tab bar translucent bydefault so add this this code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
  self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```